# Tracking a marker for an Augmented android application. Which library?

Tags: java, android, opencv, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new in Augmented Reality and I am trying to build an app that tracks a marker. The problems I have is that I can't find good enough documentation online. I am using OpenCV 3.4 and Android. When I say markers I mean:

[image]

Now in my case I could also track a ball (a red ball for example) and use that for tracking (is that proper AR though?). My main problem is how to achieve good tracking of a marker.. What should I use ? ArCore/OpenCV/Vuforia?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia is probably not the solution here, and ARCore is limited to new Android OS version - you have to decide if you're ok with that.

For detecting a red ball - there are tons of articles out there, you should simply try it out. Most methods rely on `OpenCV`'s [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) or [HoughCircles](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d). The tracking quality depends on your use case and performance requirements - the more complex the environment in which the detection happens (visually-wise), the more filters and algorithms you need in order to isolate your ball, and the more filters and algorithms you apply, the better the result is, but it might affect the frame rate. It is a matter of trial and error per your specific requirements.

For using the marker above, you can check out Aruco library with Opencv:
[Detection of ArUco Markers](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html) (I havn't tried it, though).

Comment: ARCore does not do tracking... And ArUco markers are not available on the OpenCV version of Android

Comment: ArCore is not relevant anyway, as I said. And for Aruco - you can find projects that combine it with OpenCV in Android, like this one: https://github.com/jsmith613/Aruco-Marker-Tracking-Android. However, I don't know what it can do and how good it is...

Comment: Ok the link helps. It seems that there is no straightforward solution or a simple tutorial for this.